# All my arrays are objects with "clean" property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a client side javascript project and for some reason every single array I try to create is an object with some sort of "clean" parameter. Has anyone ever seen this before, and happen to know why its happening?

```
var x = [];
console.log(x);
[clean: function]
```

Comment: It's probably being added by an extension or library.

Comment: Use a debugger, call `[].clean()` and step-into it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat like chrome extension? I'm in incognito

Comment: Some extensions can still run in incognito mode. Make sure they're disabled in Settings.

Comment: @PierPaoloRamon in in requirejs so nothings global

Comment: @DesertIvy just manually disabled all, still happening

Comment: it's a prototype method on Array.prototype, that's how they show up in devtools... it won't affect normal array usage

Comment: Launch a random page (google.com, whatever) go to the console and do `[].clean()`. At least you'll see if the function is added by a Chrome extension or some library in your project. I mean, if you'll get `undefined is not a function` it means the problem lies in your project specifically.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript libraries/frameworks?  jQuery, Underscore.js, Prototype, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is this Wanelo Javascript file:

`//cdn-saveit.wanelo.com/bookmarklet/3/save.js`

You have no idea how difficult this was to track down...

It adds a `clean` function to `Array`, which seemingly removes `undefined` elements from it. From the minified JavaScript:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function() {
    var t;        
    for(t=0; t < this.length;) 
    void 0 === this[t] && (this.splice(t,1), t--), t++;        
    return this;
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var x = [undefined, 1, 2, undefined, 3];
console.log(x.clean());
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: As a reference, in es5 this should have been `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, { enumerable: false, configurable: true, value: … })`

Comment: @PierPaoloRamon Do you work at Wanelo? Is this an issue with that save script, or is the code ok / fine?

Comment: That was a gratuitous comment on ES6. If you have to modify a native prototype then make it non-enumerable. (I don’t work for Wanelo)

Comment: I work for Wanelo, and we are looking into this. Thanks for reporting!